# Catching the last xpath element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Could someone please help with how can I get the last `xpath` element?

I'm currently using the code.

```
String cardNum = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='card-number']/p")).getText();
```

I understand the method `[last()]` can be used to capture the last element and its value.

Thanks,

Az.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='card-number']/p)[last()]")).getText();
```